# "The page has expired. Please refresh and try again."

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've read pretty much all related questions, but none of theme seemed to have the solution I'm looking for.

The error says "Please refresh and try again.", but when you refresh that page, you simply stay on that page and don't get redirected.

Is there a way to make the refresh happen anyway? Or even simply redirect to another page instead of staying on the error page?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please post relevant code and what you have tried to do to resolve this?

Comment: @user10341554 How would any code be relevant to this question? It's built in Laravel feature. I haven't changed code regarding this behaviour.

Comment: It's built-in Laravel code which is behaving as it's supposed to. Why do you expect it to redirect without any custom code?

Comment: @apokryfos Ok. Is it expected that the error says "Please refresh", but nothing happens after the refresh too?

Comment: That message means that the CSRF token you've supplied to the server is invalid. It's only shown for pages which require CSRF validation which is pages that you arrive to via a POST request. It could not go away under certain situations such as the session not working properly or other configuration or code related reasons. What you're describing here is far too vague to speculate what that reason might be though.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel this happens mostly when you don't have `_token` in your form or session fails.

1. If you are posting form check to include `@csrf` or `{{csrf_field()}}` in your form.  (this generates hidden `_token` input
2. check the session driver if it is array or file and modify it. !!!alert - this may destroy other third package functions